# Instance created by CloudStack not opening its console

Tags: kvm, apache-cloudstack

After creating an instance from CloudStack UI, I can see the VMs:

```
    # virsh list --all
    Id    Name                           State
    ----------------------------------------------------
    1     v-2-VM                         running
    4     s-1-VM                         running
    5     r-4-VM                         running
    8     i-2-5-VM                       running
    10    i-2-3-VM                       running
```

But when I try to start a console for an instance say i-2-5-VM, i get the following:

```
    # virsh console i-2-5-VM
    Connected to domain i-2-5-VM
    Escape character is ^]
```

Hereafter the console hangs, not even the command prompt comes. Then i have to press Ctrl+] to come back to the shell. Additional information:

```
    # virsh ttyconsole i-2-5-VM
    /dev/pts/4
```

I can ping to it, but cannot ssh.
Please let me know, how can I login to my instance ?

Answer (score 0):

Start the console from the CloudStack GUI rather than the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want to see the details of the VM, you can install GUI tool **virt-manager** which will show you all the instances running on the KVM hypervisor and their all the details (nics, volumes, memory, state etc)